# Android Studio Gradle loading

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to switch to *Android Studio*, but I have some issue.

**Gradle Build** keeps loading and never stops.

I have uninstalled and installed, first RUN it works fine, but when I close and re-launch I have this Gradle issue as shown on screen-shot.

[gradle build error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkTi4.png)

Comment: Are you using a standalone version of gradle or the gradle wrapper in your project?

Answer (score 0):

This has already been asked a lot of times on SO .

1) Follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585869/android-studio-error-installing-gradle/)

and check the answer given by Nick P

2) It generally takes time to depending on your connection speed(data is of ~50MB) , so wait for somewhile!

Hope it helps.