# " app-release.apk" how to change this default generated apk name

Tags: android, android-studio

Whenever I generate a signed **apk** in Android Studio, by default it gives the name as app-release.apk...

Can we do any settings so that it should prompt and ask me the name which need to be assigned to the apk(the way it do in eclipse)

What I do is - rename the apk after it generated.
This doesn't give any errors but is there any genuine way so that i can do any changes in settings to get a prompt.

Note::

while generating apk android studio is giving me a prompt to select the location(only)[image]

Comment: 1.change build varient to release   2.select build->generate signed apk from menu bar.  In this way am generating signed apk

Comment: All the answers here are not correct.. This issue will still occur using any of them... The problem is studio caching the name of the apk artifact, and keep using the cached name instead of using the new generated one!

Answer (score 163, accepted):

***Yes we can change that but with some more attention***

[image: SeeThis]

Now add this in your **build.gradle** in your project while make sure you have checked the **build variant** of your project like `release or Debug`
so here I have set my build variant as `release` but you may select as Debug as well.

```
    buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                signingConfig getSigningConfig()
                applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                    variant.outputs.each { output ->
                        def date = new Date();
                        def formattedDate = date.format('yyyyMMddHHmmss')
                        output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent,
                                output.outputFile.name.replace("-release", "-" + formattedDate)
    //for Debug use output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent,
   //                             output.outputFile.name.replace("-debug", "-" + formattedDate)
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

> You may Do it With different Approach Like this

```
 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.status"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        setProperty("archivesBaseName", "COMU-$versionName")
    }
```

Using Set property method in build.gradle
*and Don't forget to sync the gradle before running the projects*
Hope It will solve your problem :)

> A New approach to handle this added recently by google update
> **You may now rename your build according to flavor or Variant output**
> [//Below source is from developer android documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#variant_api)
> *For more details follow the above documentation link*
> **Using the Variant API to manipulate variant outputs is broken with the new plugin. It still works for simple tasks, such as changing the APK name during build time, as shown below:**

```
// If you use each() to iterate through the variant objects,
// you need to start using all(). That's because each() iterates
// through only the objects that already exist during configuration time—
// but those object don't exist at configuration time with the new model.
// However, all() adapts to the new model by picking up object as they are
// added during execution.
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all {
        outputFileName = "${variant.name}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
    }
}
```

> Renaming .aab bundle
> This is nicely [answered by David Medenjak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52508720/how-to-change-the-generated-filename-for-app-bundles-with-gradle)

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name.startsWith("bundle")) {
        def renameTaskName = "rename${task.name.capitalize()}Aab"
        def flavor = task.name.substring("bundle".length()).uncapitalize()
        tasks.create(renameTaskName, Copy) {
            def path = "${buildDir}/outputs/bundle/${flavor}/"
            from(path)
            include "app.aab"
            destinationDir file("${buildDir}/outputs/renamedBundle/")
            rename "app.aab", "${flavor}.aab"
        }

        task.finalizedBy(renameTaskName)
    }
//@credit to David Medenjak for this block of code
}
```

> Is there need of above code

**What I have observed in the latest version of the android studio 3.3.1**

*The rename of .aab bundle is done by the previous code there don't require any task rename at all.*

Hope it will help you guys. :)

Comment: so use the string there in the like "Abhishek Chaubey" instaed of formattedDate

Comment: Is it possible to add `versionName` somehow?

Comment: @AbhishekChaubey I'm not able to run the code through Android Studio anymore after changing the apk name, any idea? please help...it shows `The APK file /Users/.../outputs/apk/NewName-debug-20161004172815.apk does not exist on disk.`

Comment: @BeeingJk rebuild the project or once close the android studio and delete output folder from the build directory and then rebuild the project or try it by cleaning .hope it may help you

Comment: @AbhishekChaubey I am also facing the same issue. As you said, I cleaned the code, deleted build folders, restarted studio. Still not getting

Comment: @NigamPatro is there any log you are getting after applying the above solution,please elaborate your problem

Comment: As @BeeingJk mentioned the issue. I am also facing the issue.

Comment: As of Android Studio 3.0 output.outputFile is read only. @johnny-doe's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28249036/app-release-apk-how-to-change-this-default-generated-apk-name#46028128) is the new solution.

Comment: This will not solve the issue.. the problem is the studio caching the first output name, and not updating it to the new one

Comment: How we can add architectures name to apk name? For exampe "MyApp_V223_151118_R_arm.apk" and "MyApp_V223_151118_R_x86.apk"

Comment: give this Cannot set the value of read-only property 'outputFile' for

Comment: the last hint worked fine for me, gradle version 3.2.1

Comment: Anyone know how set the app bundle name in similar fashion as it still taking app.aab as name by default even after following above mentioned steps.

Comment: @shaby i have updated the code  for your question.
it is very late but hope it will help you

Comment: Please where can I locate these config files? Thanks @AbhishekChaubey

Comment: If you@Vixson mean where you put this code then it will be in your app build.gradle file write the code inside your android{ } tag

Comment: setProperty("archivesBaseName", "COMU-$versionName") did the trick for me, thanks @AbhishekChaubey

Answer (score 97):

You might get the error with the latest android gradle plugin (**3.0**):

> Cannot set the value of read-only property 'outputFile'

According to [the migration guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#variant_api), we should use the following approach now:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all {
        outputFileName = "${applicationName}_${variant.buildType.name}_${defaultConfig.versionName}.apk"
    }
}
```

Note 2 main changes here:

1. `all` is used now instead of `each` to iterate over the variant outputs.
2. `outputFileName` property is used instead of mutating a file reference.

Comment: Now this is the correct answer of October 2017 for Android Studio 3.0 Beta 7. Thanks.

Comment: In my case `${applicationName}` resolved to `BuildType_Decorated{name=applicationName, debuggable=false, testCoverageEnabled=false, jniDebuggable=false, pseudoLocalesEnabled=false, renderscript...` (shortnened for clarity). This caused packaging to fail. For me `${applicationId}` or `${archivesBaseName}` were better options. Also `${defaultConfig.versionName}` for me is null. So `${applicationId}_${variant.name}-${variant.versionName}` is what I ended up with.

Comment: Not quite sure how to resolve this (appears in **Gradle Messages** when syncing *(Gradle v4.4)* `No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.all() is applicable for argument types: (build_8pov2vcee3orzmdxelrhjbbwu$_run_closure2$_closure6$_closure12$_closure13) values: [build_8pov2vcee3orzmdxelrhjbbwu$_run_closure2$_closure6$_closure12$_closure13@296351f6]
Possible solutions: tail(), any(), tail(), last(), last(), add(java.lang.Object)` I added this to `defaultConfig{}` block  and to `buildTypes {release{}}` block, both giving the same error

Comment: @KGCybeX Usually this code is used in `android{}` section on the same level as `defaultConfig{}`. Although, you can use it outside of `android{}` using `android.applicationVariants.all { }` syntax

Comment: @JohnnyDoe Thanks for the help, I have just done as you suggested, no luck. I added to the end of the `android{}` block, still gives error mentioned above -> Gradle with error at bottom https://pastebin.com/Kk2JwPGA

Comment: Work in Gradle 5.1.1

Answer (score 70):

Here is a much shorter way:

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    applicationId "com.blahblah.example"
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    setProperty("archivesBaseName", applicationId + "-v" + versionCode + "(" + versionName + ")")
    //or so
    archivesBaseName = "$applicationId-v$versionCode($versionName)"
}
```

It gives you name com.blahblah.example-v1(1.0)-debug.apk (in debug mode)

Android Studio add versionNameSuffix by build type name by default, if you want override this, do next:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        ...
        versionNameSuffix "-MyNiceDebugModeName"
    }
    release {
        ...
    }
}
```

Output in debug mode: com.blahblah.example-v1(1.0)-MyNiceDebugModeName.apk

Comment: Thanks. This is fastest option!

Comment: Side note you can add archiveBaseName to your local gradle.properties file.

Comment: It really seems more clear. Why is this not the prefered solution?

Comment: Checked that this works in AndroidStudio v.4.1 and Gradle v.6.5

Comment: any idea how to get rid of `-debug` tail?

Comment: Uh, this affects the version name of the app not the file name: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41665729/1866373

Comment: Is it possible to use the app-name instead of package-name?

Comment: For Kotlin DSL use `archivesName` instead of `archivesBaseName`.

Comment: "you can add archiveBaseName to your local gradle.properties file" @Ge3ng 
-How do we do that? is it similar to how we do in build.gradle file

Comment: Gradle.properties is a key value pair file.

Answer (score 55):

**(EDITED to work with Android Studio 3.0 and Gradle 4)**

I was looking for a more complex apk filename renaming option and I wrote this solution that renames the apk with the following data:

- **flavor**
- **build type**
- **version**
- **date**

You would get an apk like this: **myProject_dev_debug_1.3.6_131016_1047.apk**.

[You can find the whole answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40016854/3568782). Hope it helps!

In the build.gradle:

```
android {

    ...

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            ...
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        prod {
            applicationId "com.feraguiba.myproject"
            versionCode 3
            versionName "1.2.0"
        }
        dev {
            applicationId "com.feraguiba.myproject.dev"
            versionCode 15
            versionName "1.3.6"
        }
    }

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all { output ->
            def project = "myProject"
            def SEP = "_"
            def flavor = variant.productFlavors[0].name
            def buildType = variant.variantData.variantConfiguration.buildType.name
            def version = variant.versionName
            def date = new Date();
            def formattedDate = date.format('ddMMyy_HHmm')

            def newApkName = project + SEP + flavor + SEP + buildType + SEP + version + SEP + formattedDate + ".apk"

            outputFileName = new File(newApkName)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: great. Only improvement to be made is a constant filename (without version or date) for some flavors or buildType (flavor=="dev" || buildType="debug")

Comment: the "all" instead of "each" seems important here.

Comment: Gives error `> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: variantConfiguration for class: com.android.build.gradle.internal.variant.ApplicationVariantData`. Why not simply change to `buildType = variant.buildType.name`?

Comment: it says `"file.apk" is not writeable`

Comment: You do realize what this line does right "variant.productFlavors[0]"? You will never get actual built product flavor, instead the first flavor that appears in your gradle file.

Comment: For Android Studio 4 
Instead of
def buildType = variant.variantData.variantConfiguration.buildType.name

Should be
def buildType = variant.buildType.name

Answer (score 53):

I modified @Abhishek Chaubey answer to change the whole file name:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                project.ext { appName = 'MyAppName' }
                def formattedDate = new Date().format('yyyyMMddHHmmss')
                def newName = output.outputFile.name
                newName = newName.replace("app-", "$project.ext.appName-") //"MyAppName" -> I set my app variables in the root project
                newName = newName.replace("-release", "-release" + formattedDate)
                //noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
                output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, newName)
            }
        }
    }
    debug {
    }
}
```

This produces a file name like: `MyAppName-release20150519121617.apk`

Comment: How do you add a variable in Gradle

Comment: @Mehdiway consider gradle another language, you can see date declared in the code like `def formattedDate`.

Comment: In order to add a custom 'appName' property, add code like this to your root project: 
`project.ext {
    appName = 'MyApplicatioName'
}
`

Comment: @ranma2913 I'm not able to run the code through Android Studio anymore after changing the apk name, any idea? please help...it shows The APK file /Users/.../outputs/apk/NewName-debug-20161004172815.apk does not exist on disk.

Comment: Instead of setting manually MyAppName, `rootProject.name` will give you project name like in eclipse.

Comment: I prefer doing it in a `build-extras.gradle` file instead to avoid messing up the default one. Also I'm using this for the name of the file to have the package name instead: `"${variant.applicationId}-${variant.name}-${formattedDate}.apk"`, this gives something like `com.mycompany.myapp-release-20161004172815.apk`

Comment: As of Android Studio 3.0 `output.outputFile` is read only.
@johnny-doe's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28249036/app-release-apk-how-to-change-this-default-generated-apk-name#46028128) is the new solution.

Answer (score 8):

I wrote more universal solution based on @Fer answer.

It also should work with flavor and build type based configuration of `applicationId`, `versionName`, `versionCode`.

In the build.gradle:

```
android {
    ...
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            def appId = variant.applicationId
            def versionName = variant.versionName
            def versionCode = variant.versionCode
            def flavorName = variant.flavorName // e. g. free
            def buildType = variant.buildType // e. g. debug
            def variantName = variant.name // e. g. freeDebug

            def apkName = appId + '_' + variantName + '_' + versionName + '_' + versionCode + '.apk';
            output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parentFile, apkName)
        }
    }
}
```

Example apk name: `com.example.app_freeDebug_1.0_1.apk`

For more information about `variant` variable see [ApkVariant](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/build/+/android-8.1.0_r14/gradle/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/api/ApkVariant.java) and [BaseVariant](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/build/+/android-8.1.0_r14/gradle/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/api/BaseVariant.java) interfaces definition.

Answer (score 6):

add `android.applicationVariants.all` block like below in you app level gradle

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            lintOptions {
                disable 'MissingTranslation'
            }
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.all {
                    outputFileName = "${applicationId}_${versionCode}_${variant.flavorName}_${variant.buildType.name}.apk"
                }
            }
        }
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
            versionNameSuffix '_debug'
        }
    }
```

available at 2019/03/25

Answer (score 4):

### For newer android studio Gradle

**AppName** is your app name you want so replace it
**variantName** will be default Selected variant or flavor
**Date will Today's date**, So need to do any changes just paste it

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all {
        def variantName = variant.name
        def versionName = variant.versionName
        def formattedDate = new Date().format('dd-MM-YYYY')
        outputFileName = "AppName_${variantName}_D_${formattedDate}_V_${versionName}.apk"
    }
}
```

### Output:

**AppName_release_D_26-04-2021_V_1.2.apk**

Answer (score 4):

With the `flavors and split APK` this is how it works for `APK` files, not the `Bundle / AAB files`

```
android {
    ....

    productFlavors {
        aFlavor {
            applicationId "com.a"
        
            versionCode 5
            versionName "1.0.5"

            signingConfig signingConfigs.signingA
        }
        bFlavor {
            applicationId "com.b"

            versionCode 5
            versionName "1.0.5"

            signingConfig signingConfigs.signingB
        }
        cFlavor {
            applicationId "com.c"

            versionCode 3
            versionName "1.0.3"

            signingConfig signingConfigs.signingC
        }
    }

    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'
            universalApk false
        }
    }

    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all { output ->
            // New one or Updated one
            output.outputFileName = "${variant.getFlavorName()}-${variant.buildType.name}-v${versionCode}_${versionName}-${new Date().format('ddMMMyyyy_HH-mm')}-${output.getFilter(com.android.build.OutputFile.ABI)}.apk"
            // Old one
            // output.outputFileName = "${variant.buildType.name}-v${versionCode}_${versionName}-${new Date().format('ddMMMyyyy_HH-mm')}.apk"
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Result

### For aFlvour

- **Release**

  `aFlavor-release-v5_1.0.5-16Jan2020_21-26-arm64-v8a.apk`

  `aFlavor-release-v5_1.0.5-16Jan2020_21-26-x86_64.apk`

  `aFlavor-release-v5_1.0.5-16Jan2020_21-26-x86.apk`
- **Debug**

  `aFlavor-debug-v5_1.0.5-16Jan2020_21-26-arm64-v8a.apk`

  `aFlavor-debug-v5_1.0.5-16Jan2020_21-26-x86_64.apk`

  `aFlavor-debug-v5_1.0.5-16Jan2020_21-26-x86.apk`

### For bFlavor

Similar name as above just change the prefix **`aFlavor`** with **`bFlavor`** like

- `bFlavor-release-v5_1.0.5-16Jan2020_21-26-arm64-v8a.apk`

### For cFlavor

Similar name as above just change the prefix **`aFlavor`** with **`cFlavor`**
and, **`versionCode`** and **`versionName`** as respected

- `cFlavor-release-v3_1.0.3-16Jan2020_21-26-arm64-v8a.apk`

---

For more detail review this ***[Que-Ans](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59650844/1684864)*** thread

Answer (score 3):

Not renaming it, but perhaps generating the name correctly in the first place would help?  [Change apk name with Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22126299/change-apk-name-with-gradle)

Answer (score 3):

I've realised that a lot of the answers didn't cater for different buildTypes, here is how I handle it.

```java
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
   variant.outputs.all {                                       
      def appVersionName = "${applicationId}v${versionCode}#${versionName}"
      
      switch (buildType.name) {
          case "debug": {  
              outputFileName = "${appVersionName}-staging.apk"                                            
              break
          }
         case "release": {
              outputFileName = "${appVersionName}.apk"
              break
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Attributes like applicationId, versionCode and versionName are already defined in your defaultConfig. You can just easily format into something that gives it a more meaningful and context naming whenever you generate an APK.

This is how it'll churn out.

```
com.delacrixmorgan-v1.0.0#1.apk
com.delacrixmorgan-v1.0.0#1-staging.apk
```

Besides that, if you guys want to learn more about Gradle. I've went into length in this Medium article.
[Supercharging your Android Gradle](https://medium.com/bugless/supercharging-your-android-gradle-98c8b8d5effd)

Comment: Unrotunately `case` doesn't work for me, so I made it easier:

`def name = "${applicationId}-${versionName}-${versionCode}"; def suffix = buildType.name == 'debug' ? '-debug' : ''; outputFileName = "${name}${suffix}.apk";`

Answer (score 2):

First rename your module from **app** to i.e. **SurveyApp**

Second add this to your project top-level (root project) gradle. It's working with **Gradle 3.0**

```
//rename apk for all sub projects
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate { project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.all {
                    outputFileName = "${project.name}-${variant.name}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the following code in build.gradle(Module:app)

```
android {
    ......
    ......
    ......
    buildTypes {
        release {
            ......
            ......
            ......
            /*The is the code fot the template of release name*/
            applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.each { output ->
                    def formattedDate = new Date().format('yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm')
                    def newName = "Your App Name " + formattedDate
                    output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, newName)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the release build name will be  **Your App Name 2018-03-31 12-34**

Answer (score 1):

**My solution may also be of help to someone.**

Tested and Works on *IntelliJ 2017.3.2* with *Gradle 4.4*

**Scenario:**

I have 2 flavours in my application, and so I wanted each release to be named appropriately according to each flavor.

The code below will be placed into your module gradle build file found in:

`{app-root}/app/build.gradle`

Gradle code to be added to `android{ }` block:

```
android {
    // ...

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode 10
        versionName "1.2.3_build5"
    }

    buildTypes {
        // ...

        release {
            // ...

            applicationVariants.all { 
                variant.outputs.each { output ->
                    output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, output.outputFile.name.replace(output.outputFile.name, variant.flavorName + "-" + defaultConfig.versionName + "_v" + defaultConfig.versionCode + ".apk"))
                }
            }

        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        myspicyflavor {
            applicationIdSuffix ".MySpicyFlavor"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }

        mystandardflavor {
            applicationIdSuffix ".MyStandardFlavor"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
}
```

The above provides the following APKs found in `{app-root}/app/`:

```
myspicyflavor-release-1.2.3_build5_v10.apk
mystandardflavor-release-1.2.3_build5_v10.apk
```

Hope it can be of use to someone.

*For more info, see other answers mentioned in the question*

Answer (score 1):

android studio 4.1.1

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
  variant.outputs.all { output ->
    def reversion = "118"
    def date = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").format(new Date())
    def versionName = defaultConfig.versionName
    outputFileName = "MyApp_${versionName}_${date}_${reversion}.apk"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

put this code in build.gradle(app)

```
 android {

      .......
     applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.all {
                outputFileName = "Name_of_App.apk"
            }}
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way - in build.gradle(app):

```
android {
    compileSdk 31
    project.archivesBaseName = "Scanner"

    defaultConfig {
```

And - you will receive : Scanner-release.apk

Answer (score 1):

Here i made my apk name

> branchName_versionName_versionCode.apk

example

> development_1.5.3_10.apk

get branch name from here

```
def getBranchName = { ->
    try {
        def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
        exec {
            commandLine 'git', 'rev-parse', '--abbrev-ref', 'HEAD'
            standardOutput = stdout
        }
        println "Git Current Branch = " + stdout.toString()
        return stdout.toString().trim()
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        println "Exception = " + e.getMessage()
        return null;
    }
}
```

then get your variants from here and set file name

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        def appId = variant.applicationId
        def versionName = variant.versionName
        def versionCode = variant.versionCode
        def flavorName = variant.flavorName // e. g. free
        def buildType = variant.buildType // e. g. debug
        def variantName = variant.name // e. g. freeDebug

        def apkName = getBranchName() + '_' + versionName + '_' + versionCode + '.apk';
        output.outputFileName = apkName
    }
}
```

Put this script in `android` tag in `app/build.gradle` file

```
android {
def getBranchName ................
..................
..................
applicationVariants.all ..........
..................
..................
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be helpful.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        shrinkResources true
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                project.ext { appName = 'MyAppName' }
                def formattedDate = new Date().format('yyyyMMddHHmmss')
                def newName = output.outputFile.name
                newName = newName.replace("app-", "$project.ext.appName-")
                newName = newName.replace("-release", "-release" + formattedDate)
                output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, newName)
            }
        }
    }
}
productFlavors {
    flavor1 {
    }
    flavor2 {
        proguardFile 'flavor2-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work.

****Kotlin : 1.8.20
Android Studio : Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1
Gradle : gradle-7.5.1-bin.zip****

```
android {    
  ..............

applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        def formattedDate = new Date().format('yyyyMMdd')
        def flavorName = "${variant.flavorName}"
        def buildName = variant.buildType.name
        def versionName = variant.versionName
        def versionCode = variant.versionCode
        def fileName = "${formattedDate}_HELLO_Android_${flavorName}_${buildName}_v${versionName}(${versionCode}).apk"
        variant.outputs.all {
            outputFileName = fileName
        }
    }

}
```

**Preview :**

20230822_HELLO_Android_appStoreLive_debug_v4.2.4(196).apk