# Android Studio - Rename app-release.apk to package name

Tags: android, apk, rename

Firstly, I'm trying to do an update over an old apk on play store,
And I'm curious if the generated signed apk with the default name "app-release"
Should i rename that to the same name as my new apk com.site.radio?

What I mean..

I have generated a signed apk but it's named "app-release" by default,
I'd like to change that name to the same name as my package: com.site.radio

I've tried putting this in the build.gradel:

```
    project.ext.set("archivesBaseName", "com.site.radio");
```

But when I generate a new signed apk it's name becomes:

com.site.radio-release

How do you remove the -release part?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hope this solve your problem.[Try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28249036/app-release-apk-how-to-change-this-default-generated-apk-name)

Comment: Can you not just rename the app-release.apk?
Does this generated signed apk need to be the same name as the package com.site.radio for an update to work?

Comment: No. The name of the apk has nothing to do with the update process. You can rename it to whatever you want. The key part for doing an update is, you have to sign the new apk with the same certificate that you used for signing your previous version's apk.

Comment: Ok I think everything is sorted, I managed to sign it with the old .keystore from eclipse.. so I can just rename app-release.apk to com.site.radio?

Comment: Yeah. Like I said before, the name of the file is of no importance.

Comment: Ok thank you... I can't believe I got this far, good stuff!