# How to Rename and Generate all APK & Bundle from Gradle with Product flavour and APK Splits

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, groovy, build.gradle

### As I have tried these 2 ways (using a single at a time) to rename the APK

### Option - **One**

```
// To Change the APK and Bundle Name
archivesBaseName = "${name}-v${versionCode}_${versionName}-${new Date().format('ddMMMyyyy_HH-mm')}"
```

### Option - **Two**

(for this also tried to change the - `variant.outputs.all` to `variant.outputs.each`)

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all { output ->
        output.outputFileName = "${variant.buildType.name}-v${versionCode}_${versionName}-${new Date().format('ddMMMyyyy_HH-mm')}.apk"
    }
}
```

---

When I use option **One**,

> **Issue** - it generates all splits but it overrides the flavor config with the
> last flavor written in Gradle.

Also, try to put option **One** only once in `defaultConfig` but as productFlavours written after that it returns the `null` value in `versionCode` and `versionName`.

```
productFlavors {
    aFlavor {
        applicationId "com.a"
        
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.0.5"

        signingConfig signingConfigs.signingA

        // To Change the APK and Bundle Name
        archivesBaseName = "${name}-v${versionCode}_${versionName}-${new Date().format('ddMMMyyyy_HH-mm')}"
    }
    bFlavor {
        applicationId "com.b"

        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.0.5"

        signingConfig signingConfigs.signingB

        // To Change the APK and Bundle Name
        archivesBaseName = "${name}-v${versionCode}_${versionName}-${new Date().format('ddMMMyyyy_HH-mm')}"
    }
    cFlavor {
        applicationId "com.c"

        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.0.3"

        signingConfig signingConfigs.signingC

        // To Change the APK and Bundle Name
        archivesBaseName = "${name}-v${versionCode}_${versionName}-${new Date().format('ddMMMyyyy_HH-mm')}"
    }
}
```

---

When I use option **Two**,

> **Issue** - it generates the correct name but generates a single APK file.

```
splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'
        universalApk false
    }
}

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all { output ->
        output.outputFileName = "${variant.buildType.name}-v${versionCode}_${versionName}-${new Date().format('ddMMMyyyy_HH-mm')}.apk"
    }
}
```

> **Issue for bundle** - not able to rename the bundle using option **Two**.

Comment: http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor.html

why not to use some standard properties like `versionNameSuffix` or `applicationIdSuffix` ?

Comment: @daggett Agree, but what if application ID and version name are totally different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per ***[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59742089/1684864)*** answer, you can go with **`Option - Two`** with minor changes as mentioned below only works for `APK`, not the `Bundle / AAB files` (for bundle refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76961382/1684864))

```
splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'
        universalApk false
    }
}

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all { output ->
        // New one or Updated one
        output.outputFileName = "${variant.getFlavorName()}-${variant.buildType.name}-v${versionCode}_${versionName}-${new Date().format('ddMMMyyyy_HH-mm')}-${output.getFilter(com.android.build.OutputFile.ABI)}.apk"
        // Old one
        // output.outputFileName = "${variant.buildType.name}-v${versionCode}_${versionName}-${new Date().format('ddMMMyyyy_HH-mm')}.apk"
    }
}
```

Also, remove the line from each Flavor's block

```
// To Change the APK and Bundle Name
archivesBaseName = "${name}-v${versionCode}_${versionName}-${new Date().format('ddMMMyyyy_HH-mm')}"
```

---

By this, you get the output file name like this

### For aFlvour

- **Release**

`aFlavor-release-v5_1.0.5-16Jan2020_21-26-arm64-v8a.apk`

`aFlavor-release-v5_1.0.5-16Jan2020_21-26-x86_64.apk`

`aFlavor-release-v5_1.0.5-16Jan2020_21-26-x86.apk`

- **Debug**

`aFlavor-debug-v5_1.0.5-16Jan2020_21-26-arm64-v8a.apk`

`aFlavor-debug-v5_1.0.5-16Jan2020_21-26-x86_64.apk`

`aFlavor-debug-v5_1.0.5-16Jan2020_21-26-x86.apk`

### For bFlavor

Similar name as above just change the prefix **`aFlavor`** with **`bFlavor`** like

`bFlavor-release-v5_1.0.5-16Jan2020_21-26-arm64-v8a.apk`

### For cFlavor

Similar name as above just change the prefix **`aFlavor`** with **`cFlavor`**
and, **`versionCode`** and **`versionName`** as respected

`cFlavor-release-v3_1.0.3-16Jan2020_21-26-arm64-v8a.apk`

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using `universalApk false`, Gradle generates different output apk for each ABI. So you have to add ABI name to your output filename. The  `output.getFilter(com.android.build.OutputFile.ABI)` expression returns current ABI name.
Please look at the following example:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all { output ->
        output.outputFileName = "${variant.buildType.name}-${output.getFilter(com.android.build.OutputFile.ABI)}-v${versionCode}_${versionName}-${new Date().format('ddMMMyyyy_HH-mm')}.apk"
    }
}
```

Comment: And what if I also want to add the flavor name in the output file? And what about the bundle's output file name?

Comment: Got the solution for flavor name: `variant.getFlavorName()` Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52536094/1684864

Answer (score 2):

These solutions do not work for aab (bundle). Only APK.

Comment: Yes, as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59774018/1684864 and for Bundle, I also ask the question but it is marked as duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/63533131/1684864

Comment: See my solution which works for both bundle/apk

Answer (score 1):

Remove `app_name` from `string.xml` file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias 'your key alias'
            keyPassword 'your password'
            storeFile file('path of your keystore')
            storePassword 'your password'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 28
    flavorDimensions "default"
    project.archivesBaseName = "ProjectName";
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "Your package name"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.all { //output ->

                    outputFileName = "YourAppName-${variant.baseName}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
                }
            }
        }
        debug {

        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        dev {
            versionCode 778899 // your versioncode
            versionName "v.1.1.BUILD_NUM"  // your version name
            applicationIdPrefix ".dev" // your application package name like as com.a
            resValue "string", "app_name", "Your App Name"

        }
        live {
            versionCode 778899 // your versioncode
            versionName "v.1.1.BUILD_NUM"  // your version name
            applicationIdPrefix ".dev" // your application package name like as com.a
            resValue "string", "app_name", "Your App Name"

        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
   // Here your application gradle
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for bundle or APK. But I can't make it work for both without commenting in/out the necessary lines. If anyone has an idea about that?

```
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.all {
                if (variant.buildType.name == "release") {
        //              outputFileName = createCopyTaskAPK("prefix", variant.productFlavors[0].name, variant.name.capitalize())
                        outputFileName = createCopyTaskBundle("prefix", variant.productFlavors[0].name, variant.name.capitalize())
                }
            }
        }
```

Task for bundle:

```
ext.createCopyTaskBundle = { productName, variantName, taskSuffix ->
    def moveBundleTask = tasks.create(name: "move${taskSuffix}", type: Exec) {
        def input = new File("$projectDir\\$variantName\\release\\" + productName + "-" + variantName + "-release.aab")
        def folder = new File("$projectDir/$variantName")
        commandLine "copy.bat", input.path, "$projectDir\\apks\\${variantName}.aab", folder.path
        workingDir = rootProject.getProjectDir().getAbsolutePath()
        ignoreExitValue true
        dependsOn "bundle$taskSuffix"
    }
    tasks["bundle$taskSuffix"].finalizedBy = [moveBundleTask]

    return productName + "-" + variantName + "-release.aab"
}
```

Task for APK:

```
ext.createCopyTaskAPK = { productName, variantName, taskSuffix ->
    def moveAPKTask = tasks.create(name: "apk${taskSuffix}", type: Exec) {
        def input = new File("$projectDir\\$variantName\\release\\" + productName + "-" + variantName + "-release.apk")
        def folder = new File("$projectDir/$variantName")
        commandLine "copy.bat", input.path, "$projectDir\\bundles\\${variantName}.apk", folder.path
        workingDir = rootProject.getProjectDir().getAbsolutePath()
        ignoreExitValue true
        dependsOn "assemble$taskSuffix"
    }
    tasks["assemble$taskSuffix"].finalizedBy = [moveAPKTask]

    return productName + "-" + variantName + "-release.apk"
}
```

Content of copy.bat for windows:

```
ECHO COPYING %1 to %2
COPY %1 %2
```

Answer (score -3):

You have to set different flavors if you want to have different output apks.