# Android studio gradle HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

Tags: linux, ubuntu, android-studio, gradle

**My problem**

I recently install android studio in Ubuntu 14.

But I have problem in gradle build execution.

gradle not completed for any project even hello world project

**What I am tried**

1.
 File Menu - > Invalidate Caches/ Restart..

2.Increase the heap size manually using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34469659/3879847)

3.[Android Studio Gradle loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736927/android-studio-gradle-loading)

But no luck for me.

**Error details**

```
Tooling API is using target Gradle version: 2.4.
Starting a new Gradle Daemon for this build (subsequent builds will be faster).
Starting daemon process: workingDir = /home/knonex19/.gradle/daemon/2.4, daemonArgs: [/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java, -XX:MaxPermSize=256m, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Xmx1024m, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Duser.country=IN, -Duser.language=en, -Duser.variant, -cp, /home/knonex19/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.4-all/6r4uqcc6ovnq6ac6s0txzcpc0/gradle-2.4/lib/gradle-launcher-2.4.jar, org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon, 2.4, /home/knonex19/.gradle, /home/knonex19/.gradle/daemon, 10800000, 3a17e311-fb84-4407-a62b-c87d02683ab5, -XX:MaxPermSize=256m, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Xmx1024m, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Duser.country=IN, -Duser.language=en, -Duser.variant]
Starting process 'Gradle build daemon'. Working directory: /home/knonex19/.gradle/daemon/2.4 Command: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xmx1024m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=IN -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp /home/knonex19/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.4-all/6r4uqcc6ovnq6ac6s0txzcpc0/gradle-2.4/lib/gradle-launcher-2.4.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 2.4 /home/knonex19/.gradle /home/knonex19/.gradle/daemon 10800000 3a17e311-fb84-4407-a62b-c87d02683ab5 -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xmx1024m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=IN -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant
Successfully started process 'Gradle build daemon'
An attempt to start the daemon took 0.902 secs.
Connected to daemon DaemonInfo{pid=2796, address=[ec70070e-7a08-4520-a3ae-0c0b751449aa port:38689, addresses:[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, /127.0.0.1]], idle=false, context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=3a17e311-fb84-4407-a62b-c87d02683ab5,javaHome=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle,daemonRegistryDir=/home/knonex19/.gradle/daemon,pid=2796,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=IN,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]}. Dispatching request Build{id=9fe736cb-042e-4d0f-a55b-f95626396a77.1, currentDir=/home/knonex19/Desktop/tummyfulltabletpos}.
[ 351800]   WARN - ConfigurableExtensionPointUtil - Can't find parent for project.propCompiler (Compiler)
```

Anybody solve my issue thanks..

Comment: What happens when you use gradle command line and take Android Studio out of the picture? There is very little to go on in you question.