# Gradle error: could not execute build using gradle distribution

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

After I updated Android Studio to version 0.2.7, I got the following error:

```
 org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not execute build
 using Gradle distribution
'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip'.: Could
 not execute build using Gradle distribution
'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip'.
```

This is my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 17
}
}
```

Does anyone know this error?

Comment: not too sure this will work but it's worth a try. https://plus.google.com/110937808291147673063/posts/bThHvazYe5q

Answer (score 63):

I had the same issue, can't say I know what caused it, but I just closed Android Studio, renamed the `c:\users\MY USERNAME\.gradle` directory to `old-.gradle` and then re-launched Android Studio.

Android studio then re-created the directory and automatically downloaded the gradle zip file and set it all up.

Seems to all be fine but to be honest I don't know what this directory is nor what the root cause of the problem was either, so proceed with caution and keep the old `.gradle` folder around for a bit until you're happy all is working fine.

Comment: This worked for me, on OSX though, simply removed .gradle folder from project root. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me, but it took nearly 15 minutes to restart Android Studio after deleting the .gradle folder...

Comment: Worked for Intellij IDEA Unlimited (14.0.2) with Android plugin.

Comment: Did not work for Eclipse Mars using git. 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-bin.zip'. Renamed the project .gradle file and the .gradle unter c:\users\username.

Comment: It helped, thx a lot - not removing the .gradle in project root as @woot suggested but the one in user directory as the answer suggest. Hate when this kind of errors happen - out of nowhere...

Answer (score 14):

For me the following two steps fixed the issue:

1. Make sure the Gradle build was successful
2. Android Studio - File - Invalidate Caches / Restart...

Comment: I did that, and unfortunately I am still getting this error:
"Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-all.zip'"

Comment: Are you using latest tools? I updated Android Studio and gradle a few times since 0.2.7 and never had such erros.

Comment: Yeah, I always use the latest tools.  It may have been a permissions issue on my machine, since this is a company laptop and I do not have admin rights.  I simply moved Android Studio to a different directory, and now it works.

Answer (score 8):

I suddenly had this issue in the morning after it working the night before. I tried all solutions here and failed.

I also tried installing another version of Gradle 1.8 and setting the gradle_home.

Tried restarting studio.

Eventually the tried and trusted method of restarting Windows worked for me.

All in all a frustrating waste of time.

Comment: +1 this also worked for me. I've had so many headaches since Gradle has been introduced as the new build system.

Comment: This worked at first, then gave me the same error on the second build attempt.

Answer (score 5):

I updated to 0.3.0 and had the same issue. I had to end up changing my Gradle version to classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.1+' and in build.gradle and also changing the distributionUrl to distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.8-bin.zip in the gradle-wrapper.properties file. Then I did a local import of the Gradle file. That worked for me.

Comment: I'm having this exactly problem. Can you tell me what you mean by "a local import of the Gradle file"? As in you went to import project, and chose your build.gradle? Thanks

Comment: Oops, should have added @JayWhy13

Comment: Can you please explain more, I am have same issue since 0.3.0

Comment: Same for me too... please help us :)

Comment: Just changing the classpath to "0.6.1+" worked for me.  However, I did need to restart android studio as @WarrenFaith suggested.

Comment: Not sure if this will still help you but there's an option in File to Import Project, one of the options was "Local Gradle Import" or something along those lines.

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue as well and jaywhy13 answer was good but not enough.

I had to change a setting: Settings -> Gradle -> MyProject

There you need to check the "auto import" and select "use customizable gradle wrapper". After that it should refresh gradle and you can build again. If not try a reboot of Android Studio.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, JDK environment variable settings :

e.g) JAVA_HOME -> C:\develop\java\jdk\jdk1.8.0_25
     path -> %JAVA_HOME%\bin;

eclipse
Window -> preferences -> Gradle -> Arguments -> Worksapce JRE check -> jdk(jdk1.8.0_25) choice

again Run -> gradle build :)

Answer (score 3):

```
      1- delete .gradle folder in the root directory of the app
      2- invalidate cache and restart
```

Answer (score 1):

As per answer by WarrenFaith, go to:

```
Settings -> Gradle -> Project-level settings
```

Change to **Use customizable gradle wrapper**.

Click OK and watch it build. If you still get an error at that stage, go back to:

```
Settings -> Gradle -> Project-level settings
```

Change it back to **Use default gradle wrapper (recommended)**

Click OK. That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and i solved it by deleteing gradle-wrapper.jar and gradle-wrapper.properties file of Gradle wrapper then clean rebuild work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I entered:
`[C:\Users\user\].gradle\caches\1.8\scripts` directory and deleted its content.
I didn't had to restart anything, just removed `scripts` content any rerun it.

Answer (score 0):

For me, when using IntelliJ IDEA, this error arose because I had the Java SDK, rather than an Android SDK, set at the Project level.

My fix:

- IntelliJ > File > Project Structure ...
- Project > Project SDK > [Select] 'Android API 19 Platform (java version "1.7.0_40")'

I'm on:

- IntelliJ IDEA: 13.1.3
- Gradle: 1.10
- Android Plugin for Gradle: 0.9.+

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu with Eclipse 4.3 (Kepler) and the problem was that I created the project with a minus-sign in it.

I recreated the project with no specialchars and it all worked fine

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Gradle build problems in Eclipse and by doing the following steps, the problems were solved:

- set up project to use correct java version of java 
  project properties-> java build path -> jre system (edit the current one, and add the correct java jdk or jre there)
- window->Preferences ->Gradle->Arguments-> Workspace JRE (set to the correct one)

Hope this will help those who have the same problems.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me after a java update, few things to check if you are sure your path has been set before:

1. if the path doesn't match the latest java install folder, change it (if your in eclipse check the `eclipse.ini` too to make sure your using your systems default vm (ie no VM tag) )
2. go to the java directory, there should be a 'jdk' and a 'jre' in the path, for example:

   ```
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_72\jre
   ```

   if not you probably installed the JRE only not the JDK that
3. finally if the `lib` folder of the jdk (not jre) doesnt contain `tools.jar` then you have a problem with the install

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem after doing `brew install gradle`. Perhaps it was because it was an older version. So I uninstalled and instead followed the [gradle website's install instructions](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/installation.html) and then when I did `gradle eclipse` I no longer had the `could not execute build using gradle distribution` error.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurred to me when I edited the configurations in Android Studio to use the Desktop. However, using the default(android) seems to work well without any issues.

Answer (score -1):

To correct this mistake very easily,
If you read logs. The problem occurs because of the sudden shutdown of the IDEA. And the log files do not correctly write data. Just delete the file on the path

```
C:/Users/{UserName}/.Gradle/demon/{gradleVersion}/registry.bin.lock.
```