# Error using com.google.gms: google-services: 4.3.4

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying to connect Firebase project to my app. But when I add "classpath" com.google.gms: google-services: 4.3.4" AS is giving this error:

Cause: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

What should I do?

build.gradle:

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
  apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

 buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
}
}

 task clean(type: Delete) {
 delete rootProject.buildDir
 }
```

build.gradle(app):

```
 android {
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.vogella.findpeople"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}


 dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'


implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.0'
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase: getting error: 'unable to find valid certification path to requested target' while syncing gradle project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41087330/firebase-getting-error-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-t)

Comment: No, it doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

The link I flagged should work for you. Try this

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
```

Replace your classpath with this and resync.

Comment: Yes. BUt now new error: Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.4.0.

Comment: Did you use maven in build.gradle? It would be easy if you add build.gradle (both root and app) here. This error normally occurs if the SDK tools are not up-to-date with the google play services version

Comment: Also have a look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42323328/failed-to-resolve-firebase-library-android?rq=1)

Comment: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.4.0.
Show Details

Comment: Please clearly add two build.gradle code here. One is build.gradle (app) and build.gradle (your project name).

Comment: I add two gradles. Can you take a look now,, please

Answer (score 0):

Try to move your `apply plugin:` lines to the app build.gradle file instead of the project one

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with regard to adding this `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'` but it seems like I had a bad internet connection, and when I had a strong internet connection, this error occurred, [image]

it also occurred to me that that error was also due to a poor internet connection, after I fixed that then this error occurred, [image]

this was because I included this `implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.0.0')` in `build.gradle` file within the `app` directory. So I `commented it out` and now I was able to run the flutter app in my android device. Like this, [image]