# Could not execute build using Gradle distribution

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I have the following error: "Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip'."

It only occurs if I have this in my gradle file: 
"classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'"

if I switch it back to: 
"classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'"

everything works again. This started after I updated gradle and android studio today.

I have tried just about every solution in this question but nothing helped: 
[Gradle error: could not execute build using gradle distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18673636/gradle-error-could-not-execute-build-using-gradle-distribution/18979940)

from above:
-I tried deleting the .gradle in the user folder, and restarting android studio (I also restarted my computer after several other attempts)

-gradle build is successful, I tried invalidate caches and restart. (I tried this before deleting the .gradle, would it make a difference doing it again?)

-I tried setting gradle home to several other paths but nothing helped. If I go to my android studio folder/gradle theres a gradle-4.4 folder but not any of the previous versions that work. .gradle has both 4.4 and 4.1 though.

[image]

I tried the following gradle home paths:

C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/gradle-4.4

C:/Users/Joseph/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.4-all/9br9xq1tocpiv8o6njlyu5op1/gradle-4.4

/usr/local/opt/gradle/libexec/

and path/to/gradle/libexec/

as well as the default wrapper. (which I have it set to now)

It's possible my jdk/jre are set wrong but they have been working up until now.
[image]

my project gradle:

```
    buildscript {


    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'de.richsource.gradle.plugins:gwt-gradle-plugin:0.6'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:2.3.1'


    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = "IdlePortalDefense"
        gdxVersion = '1.9.6'
        roboVMVersion = '2.3.1'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
        ashleyVersion = '1.7.0'
        aiVersion = '1.8.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
        google()
    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        implementation project(":core")
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-tools:$gdxVersion"

    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        implementation project(":core")
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"

    }
}

project(":ios") {
    apply plugin: "java"
    apply plugin: "robovm"


    dependencies {
        implementation project(":core")
        implementation "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-rt:$roboVMVersion"
        implementation "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-cocoatouch:$roboVMVersion"
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-robovm:$gdxVersion"
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"

    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"

    }
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
```

my graddle wrapper:

```
#Wed Apr 25 00:05:44 EDT 2018
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

Comment: I would try one more thing: in the Gradle wrapper properties file — _wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties_ — replace 4.4 with 4.7 and try again. It would be helpful if Android Studio gave some more information about why it can't launch Gradle! Also, have you tried running the build from the command prompt?

Comment: changing to 4.7 seems to have fixed it (I thought 4.4 was the newest for some reason). note to anyone else though that I also had to disable configuration on demand in the gradle properties file (which it tells you) AND in the compiler settings.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks FF7Squirrelman for sharing the problem the solution.
For me I have also fixed the problem by updating gradle distribution from gradle-4.4-all.zip to gradle-4.7-all.zip

The problem I got is I can "Build APK" and run it on my mobile via Android Studio. However, when I generate signed APK, i got the error same as above.

Looking around the web, it sounds like there is bug on gradle-4.4 which causes the issue and I have proceed below to solve the issue as F7Squirrelman suggested:

1. updating gradle-wrapper.properties:
   distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.7-all.zip
2. Go to File -> Setting -> Build,Execution and Deployment -> Compiler
   Uncheck the box: Configure on Demand

It will allow the project built in gradle 4.7 and finally it solves the issue.