# Android Studio Import Project - Use gradle wrapper "Disabled Option"

Tags: android, android-studio

Following the Android Migration procedures, I'm unable to complete the last step in **Import into Android Studio**:

**Export from Eclipse:**

1. Update your Eclipse ADT Plugin (you must have version 22.0 or
   higher).
2. In Eclipse, select File > Export.
3. In the window that appears, open Android and select Generate
   Gradle build files.
4. Select the project you want to export for Android Studio and
   click Finish.

**Import into Android Studio:**

1. In Android Studio, close any projects currently open. You should
   see the Welcome to Android Studio window.
2. Click Import Project.
3. Locate the project you exported from Eclipse, expand it, select
   the build.gradle file and click OK.
4. In the following dialog, leave **Use gradle wrapper selected and
   click OK. (You do not need to specify the Gradle home.)**

[image: Gradle Wrapper Option Disabled]

Answer (score 2):

do the eclipse step where you export to generate the gradle build file
stop importing your project for now and create a new one.
close android studio.
navigate on your file system to the new project.
take the "gradle" folder in there and copy it in to your project.

try again. :-)

Comment: Before I get started, when I export from Eclipse, there are 2x build.gradle files created.  1 is inside my project and the 2nd is created outside my project folder, floating in the workspace directory.  If I try to import with the file in the project folder I get the above graphic as my result.  If I import using the file floating in the workspace I'm able to "Use Graddle Wrapper", but I run into this nonsense: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585869/android-studio-error-installing-gradle

Comment: MrTisten: I created a new project using Android Studio, copied the "bundle" folder to my exported Eclipse project and replaced the entire folder with the Eclipse project containing the new "bundle" folder.  If I try to open the project I get an error, cannot locate ./idea file, If I try to Import the project I get the same error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585869/android-studio-error-installing-gradle

Comment: i'm not sure what bundle folder you're talking about. i would delete all gradle build files and start over. export from within eclipse so that the file is in your project's folder. then go to android studio and create a fresh new project and then close the it. go to that new project's folder and copy the "gradle" folder into the root of your project's folder. then go try again to import it in android studio