# Error in android studio while creating new project

Tags: android, android-studio, new-project

I have just installed android studio in my computer and when I try to create a new project, I got this error message :

Failed to import Gradle project: Could not install Gradle distribution from 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip'.
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
error in opening zip file

Comment: Try this answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/16600297/2045570

Comment: Failed to import Gradle project: Error unmarshaling return header; nested exception is: 
 java.net.SocketException: Connection reset