# New project not opened in Android studio

Tags: android, project

whenever I try to open new project in Android Studio I am getting the following error. 
How to solve this error please help

Failed to import Gradle project: Could not install Gradle distribution from 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip'.
java.net.UnknownHostException: services.gradle.org
services.gradle.org

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

Comment: Check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585869/android-studio-error-installing-gradle

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to have a working internet connection. Android studio need working internet connection to create new project.