# Cant build application with Android Studio, but can from terminal

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I have problem with building my project in android studio.

I cant do ./gradlew clean and ./gradlew build from terminal and all is completed successful.
When im trying to click "Rebuild project" in android studio, im getting error:

```
org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip'.: Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip'.
```

I think it happened, when I updated my Android Studio. Can you help me solve this problem?
Im using Kubuntu 13.10.

Comment: It is known problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585869/android-studio-error-installing-gradle. Delete user_home/.gradle folder and update gradle to 1.8.

Comment: @plastiv you mean update globally in my OS?

Comment: At your `projectRoot\gradle\gradle-wrapper.properties` file. There is link, pointing at gradle distribution. Something like: `distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.8-all.zip`. But don't forget to delete .gradle cache folder, since this is a key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to update Gradle to 1.8 and change it in project gradle Wrapper.