# Cause: error in opening zip file (android-studio)

Tags: android-studio

When I create a new project I finish the steps and click on "finish" and wait for the project to open.
But instead I see an error:

[image: Error: Cause: error in opening zip file. Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)]

I can't solve this problem.

Comment: What's in the log file?

Comment: Where can I find log file

Comment: The last line of the error output you pasted: "Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)"

Comment: yp i searched on this file but i cannot find this file :(

Comment: All: If you get this error when you're trying to create a new Android project, then you won't be able to advance to the IDE menu to look at the logs. That is, unless you know in advance where these logs are stored.

Answer (score 9):

## My Installation & problem details

I had this issue after importing a github project into Android Studio using the `File > Import Project` option. Network was fine and I had other Android Studio projects working properly so this was not a installation issue. I run `Android Studio (Preview) 0.5.4`

[image]

## The solution that worked for me

I had the luxury of comparing differences with working projects. That is how I discovered the error was due to the `distributionUrl` property in the `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file.

In the failing project this was set like `distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-all.zip`. While in the working project this was `distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.11-all.zip`. Note the difference in the version.

Updating this distributionUrl in gradle-wrapper.properties to this **1.11** link solved the issue for me.

## About the Network

I have this issue on a very restricted network and I can see that the gradle-1.10 link does point to a zip file. The network issue sounds very plausible to. Probably I already have the 1.11 zip downloaded while on another network. I's less likely (though not impossible) that the 1.10 zip is broken.

Answer (score 4):

[Android Studio error installing Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585869/android-studio-error-installing-gradle)

Your situation may be like this one. Just redownload the right gradle-1.x.zip, and replace the bad one on `~/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.x/[hash code]/`
and the restart the android-studio

**Note:** `~/.gradle/` is where the directory may be found on unixoid operating systems (e.g. Linux, OS X, ...). On Windows it's typically at `C:/Users/[NAME]/.gradle/`.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me find the bad zip file from the proxy.  Here's the command line I ran to find the offender `find ~/.gradle -name "*.zip" | xargs file | grep -v "Zip archive"` which listed a zip file as an HTML file :)

Answer (score 1):

You can erase the existing gradle zip file, then download the appropriate one from Link https://gradle.org/releases/, and copy the new one (basically replace the existing one, mine was cc 5 MB, with new one cc 80 MB). Then reload Studio, and wait.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it caused because of not properly configured HTTP proxy settings.
Android Studio created the ***gradle-1.x-bin.zip*** file with the HTML error page of my proxy server inside. Obviously it won't be able to open the zip file afterwards.

The error disappeared once I configured the HTTP proxy settings under **File > Settings > HTTP Proxy**, deleted the existing archive and restarted Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

this may help you

[Android studio - Failed to complete gradle execution - error in opening zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23828085/android-studio-failed-to-complete-gradle-execution-error-in-opening-zip-file)

delete the .gradle directories in both your home directory and in your project's root directory and try building again.

Answer (score 0):

If it says asks for disable offline mode, disable it by clicking on it again. It will download some required jar files. Then enable offline mode by checking checkbox under gradle settings for offline work. Disconnect from internet and rebuild project to see if it still works.

Answer (score 0):

I am Facing this problem....
 Go to Link https://gradle.org/releases/
 then download complete gradle file ..

Android studio -> Settings -> build tools -> gradle -> Project-level settings -> select Use local gradle distribution

then select your gradle download file

And Ok....Automatically Sync Gradle and Solve Your Problem ....