# Gradle project sync failed after reinstalling system

Tags: android, gradle

everything was fine and working this morning. Then I reinstalled my system set up my project from old files, installed android-studio and now I can't get my project to compile.
This is message I'm getting:

```
Unzipping /home/usr/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.11-all/7qd8qq8te5j4f5q9aaei3gh3lj/gradle-1.11-all.zip to /home/usr/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.11-all/7qd8qq8te5j4f5q9aaei3gh3lj
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:78)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:44)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:126)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:58)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:215)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:145)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:159)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:157)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$400(Install.java:26)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:67)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:44)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    ... 3 more
```

This is what Android-studio gives me :

```
 error in opening zip file
```

I have set it up multiple times, but wit the same result

Comment: Try one of the solution in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20399277/cause-error-in-opening-zip-file-android-studio.  I guess it should be a gradle version issue.

Answer (score 3):

Let me keep it short and simple:

`$ rm -r ~/.gradle`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to deleting the files is to download the `gradle-1.11-all.zip` file manually from http://www.gradle.org/downloads and replace the corrupted file.

There's a drop-down list with older versions towards the bottom, select **1.11**.

Replace the file here: `/home/usr/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.11-all/7qd8qq8te5j4f5q9aaei3gh3lj/gradle-1.11-all.zip`

Backup the file if you are worried in any way, safe practice :)

What's happening is LibGDX is trying to extract the files, but the zip file is corrupted. So replacing the file with a clean copy works, or if you delete it, LibGDX will download it for you automatically, so it's really the same thing.