# Android Studio 0.8.7: Error:Cause: error in opening zip file

Tags: android, android-studio, gradlew

I'm attempting to import a new gradle Android project with AS 0.8.6 (have also tried 0.8.7). When importing I get the following error

```
Error:Cause: error in opening zip file
```

From my research, this is very likely a problem with downloading the gradle wrapper.

I've tried deleting the ~/.gradle folder per the suggestion of another post on SO (https://stackoverflow.com/a/23839694/413254). Upon restart the same thing happens.

If I try to run a `./gradlew clean`, I get the following error:

```
Downloading http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.12-all.zip

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Invalid Http response
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:78)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:47)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid Http response
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1342)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:59)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:45)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:60)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:47)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    ... 3 more
```

Downloading manually (from a browser) via the url in my `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file doesn't give me any problems.

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.12-all.zip
```

EDIT:

I also see the following when doing a `./gradlew clean` after a failed attempt to download

```
Unzipping /Users/user/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.12-all/2apkk7d25miauqf1pdjp1bm0uo/gradle-1.12-all.zip to /Users/user/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.12-all/2apkk7d25miauqf1pdjp1bm0uo
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:78)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:47)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:215)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:145)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:159)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:160)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$400(Install.java:29)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:70)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:47)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    ... 3 more
```

I'm not sure it's of relevance or not, but there's a `gradle-1.12-all.zip.lck` file in the same directory with the `gradle-1.12-all.zip`.

Attempting to unzip the zip results in a  cpgz file... which turns back into a zip. According to http://osxdaily.com/2013/02/13/open-zip-cpgz-file/, that's generally an indication of a corrupt download.

Comment: I also tried creating a new project and re-installing Android Studio

Comment: Could it be a proxy or network issue that's mangling the download?

Comment: Given the situation, that seems a possibility, but I'm not doing anything special with my home network. Are there default java security settings that I should maybe tweak? I can run everything just fine on my other machine on the same network.

Comment: Looks like the download gets corrupted every time. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the `distributionUrl` in the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file to the following (note the `https` instead of plain old `http`:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.12-all.zip
```

and it worked for me. I'd imagine this is a security issue... not sure what's preventing it though. Would still love if somebody had an explanation for why this is.