# Android Gradle produce a TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file during transformClassesWithDexForRelease

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, android-api-levels

I have a project in android studio for an Android application.
The project have 6 modules (3 internals libraries, one android app module, one wearable module and one module to share code between app and wearable), everything was working well until we decided to change the minimum android sdk for the app.

It was originally compatible with 16+ and we want to make it 21+.
We tried changing only the minimum sdk, upgrading the minimum sdk and the compile sdk (to 23 and 24 or 21...) and even upgrading build tools (to 23 of 24) but nothing seems to be working...
I managed to get it working "sometimes" when I enabled the gradle daemon for a reason I really don't understand but this is not really a good option for our build on CI.

So in total despair I'm asking if anybody have a clue on what could be the problem...

The error is com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file.
I never saw it when building but we also run "connectedAndroidTest" we seems to package every module and this error happens in random module and building with --info or --debug doesn't indicate which zip file opening result in an error...

```
 1:Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':shared:transformClassesWithDexForDebugAndroidTest'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':common:messages:transformClassesWithDexForDebugAndroidTest'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
==============================================================================

3: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':common:upnp:transformClassesWithDexForDebugAndroidTest'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
==============================================================================

4: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':common:utils:transformClassesWithDexForDebugAndroidTest'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
==============================================================================
```

The complete stack:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':common:utils:transformClassesWithDexForDebugAndroidTest'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:66)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:153)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:53)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:150)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:98)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:83)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:99)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:81)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:52)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:40)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:237)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
        at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:54)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:57)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:47)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:173)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:245)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:221)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:232)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:210)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
        ... 71 more
Caused by: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexTransform.transform(DexTransform.java:423)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$3.call(TransformTask.java:178)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$3.call(TransformTask.java:174)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:55)
        ... 84 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:163)
        at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.checkLibraryClassesJar(AndroidBuilder.java:1799)
        at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.convertByteCode(AndroidBuilder.java:1464)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexTransform.transform(DexTransform.java:406)
        ... 87 more
```

Comment: did you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23828085/android-studio-failed-to-complete-gradle-execution-error-in-opening-zip-file

Comment: Yes I did... Anyway it happen on multiple environements (dev as well as in our continuous integration servers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the error is not on the gradle zip but on a jar itself, make sure your compileSdkVersion, buildToolsVersion and targetSdkVersion are coherent.

If you still have the error, try building with a different version of the android gradle plugin, I was having a similar issue with com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3 and it disappeared after upgrading to 2.2.0

Answer (score -2):

It was issue with download. Download was interrupted and now it is not able to unzip partial download. I went to the path ~.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.1-all  and deleted folder gradle-4.1-all and re run react-native run-android command.