# Error:Failed to open zip file. Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)

Tags: android

[image]

I  just   clone  this  project  ImageBluring, cannot  run  successfully.

Comment: click on option:redownload dependencies and sync project
and follow steps

Comment: try cleaning gradle caches

Comment: i  had  deleted   caches  files,    the  same  as  before

Comment: change all the dependency versions to latest one

Comment: look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23828085/android-studio-failed-to-complete-gradle-execution-error-in-opening-zip-file?rq=1)
i'm faced this problem before i wish you understand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38442901/gradles-dependency-cache-may-be-corrupt-this-sometimes-occurs-after-a-network)