# i installed latest version of Android studio i.e. 2.3.1. it shows gradle sync error

Tags: android

Gradle sync failed: Cause: error in opening zip file
                    Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23828085/android-studio-failed-to-complete-gradle-execution-error-in-opening-zip-file

Answer (score 2):

Try this steps, it may work.

1. File -> Invalidate caches / Restart
2. Shutdown Android Studio
3. Rename/remove .gradle folder in the user home directory
4. Restart Android Studio let it download all the Gradle stuff it needs
5. Gradle build success!
6. Rebuild project success!

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your gradle too. I also faced the same issue but after updating gradle it got resolved