# ionic example fails (android)

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I followed the [instruction](http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/) very carefully, yet could not make build the android version. I'm getting this:

```
Error: /Users/ali/cream/myApp/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty
at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:78)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:47)
at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:215)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:145)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:159)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:160)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$400(Install.java:29)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:70)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:47)
at  org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
... 3 more
```

Can someone help me.

Comment: have you run this command `ionic platforms add android` in console? make sure you are online. if you've already run this command try removing this platform and try again. If still same error  just use this command instead `cordova platforms add android`. IONIC is build on top of cordova so you can use cordova to build your app.

Comment: @deejay I have added already (Error: Platform android already added).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30692085/cannot-build-project-using-cordova

Comment: are you building using cordova cli?

Comment: try `cordova build android -- --ant` check if you can build using ant instead

Comment: @JaoNomani try these commands, first remove existing platform `ionic platform rm android` and then try to add it again `ionic platform add android`. Sometimes the download interrupts and the files are corrupted. Make sure you've active connection all the time during download.